# redirect after shib login coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, shibboleth-sp

I need to do the following steps:

1 - authenticate through shibboleth on local coldfusion server
2 - create security token on local coldfusion server
3 - redirect to external site passing along the security token.

Can I perform the redirect through Coldfusion (and how is that done) or do I need to do the redirect through my shibboleth config on the local server?

Comment: You should post what code you've tried and what errors you're receiving. If you want opinions on your approach, I'd suggest trying the CFML Slack workspace. You can get an invite hree https://cfml-slack.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Are you sure this is not as simple as `<cflocation url="ExternalSite.com?token=yourtoken">`?